# Different edit text size in pre lollipop and lollipop+

Tags: android, xml, android-5.0-lollipop, android-4.4-kitkat

I am making one conversation app for demo purpose. Here I am getting different layout in different devices. Don't know whats wrong.

I have added code of xml and attached an image of a problem.

Thanks in advance.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/white"

tools:context="com.caregiver.conversation.ConversationMessageView">
 <View
    android:id="@+id/view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:background="@color/colorBlack" />

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/ChatRecycl"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/rlChat"
    android:layout_below="@+id/view"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:overScrollMode="never" />


<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rlChat"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/common_action_bar_splitter" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etTextMessage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/fabSend"
        android:background="@drawable/round_corner_edittext_chat"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:hint="Type message here .. "
        android:maxHeight="100dp"
        android:padding="10dp" />


    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fabSend"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:foregroundGravity="bottom"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_send_white_anydpi"
        app:fabSize="mini" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

[This is the problem i am facing..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gOnWn.png)

Comment: set the text size manually to 15sp or whatever you want

Comment: Never hardcode dimensions.Always make different dimension file for different densities and use that to support proper alignment of layouts on diff. device.Please see https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: @AnirudhSharma that is why i said use "sp" and not "px" also put into a dimen file for different resolution

Comment: @ankitagrawal exactly

Comment: @AnikitAgrawal setting the text size didn't help. I am in learning phase. Surely will follow your suggestions.